# Informatica Repository Backup file is created by powercenter user but command is executed by pmprod user

Tags: unix, informatica-powercenter

We have UNIX based Informatica. We have recently upgraded Informatica from 9.6 to 10.1 .

We have two users:

a) pmprod - Other Application user

b) powercenter - Used for installation purpose

We have shell script file to take repository backup, which we used to run on daily basis.

> The problem is even if we execute this script from "pmprod" user, the
>   repository backup file is created by "powercenter" user, which we
>   don't want.

Before upgrade it was running successfully

[Executing shell script with pmprod user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAs3G.jpg)

After execution of script if we checked the user it shows powercenter and not pmprod. PFB screenshot

[Repository backup is created with "powercenter" user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP1JA.jpg)

We have used below command in shell script file

```
cd /app/powercenter/server10/server/bin/
pmrep connect -r PCREPO_TALEN_AWS_QA -n Administrator -X PMPASS -d PCDOMAIN_TALEN_AWS_QA
pmrep backup -o backup_qa_20170717.rep
```

Please suggest do we need to provide specific permission to any file or any workaround we need to to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to discuss a few ques.... which will help you to arrive at a solution...

First set of discussion....
so, because of this user difference, are you facing any prob?
because, the command , pmrep is using the "repository" Administrator's user and pwd to rep bkp and rep restore.

So, even if you have to restore a repository, the same user which generated the rep bkp would wrk.

I'm not sure, what prob you are facing because of this?

Did you try running a restore ? Did you face any probs?

Second set of discussion...
Can u tell me in whose user-account you ran the bkp commands?
Did you use the pmprod unix user or powercenter unix user's account to run the pmrep comands?

Answer (score 0):

Ok... that makes sense... so before you upgraded, you had pmprod as the default user for starting your powercenter processes. Now after the upgrade, you have configured for powercenter user to start your processes.. as such, any file created by an informatica command will have its owner as the informatica user which in this case is powercenter regardless of which user invokes the command. You could create a command task in workflow manager to chown the file and that will sort your problem out or look here for alternatives https://network.informatica.com/thread/12401